# Pandas dataframe groupby using cyclical data

Tags: python, pandas

I have some pricing data that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([['A','1', 2015-02-01, 20.00, 20.00, 5],
                 ['A','1', 2015-02-06, 16.00, 20.00, 8],
                 ['A','1', 2015-02-14, 14.00, 20.00, 34],
                 ['A','1', 2015-03-20, 20.00, 20.00, 5],
                 ['A','1', 2015-03-25, 15.00, 20.00, 15],
                 ['A','2', 2015-02-01, 75.99, 100.00, 22],
                 ['A','2', 2015-02-23, 100.00, 100.00, 30],
                 ['A','2', 2015-03-25, 65.00, 100.00, 64],
                 ['B','3', 2015-04-01, 45.00, 45.00, 15],
                 ['B','3', 2015-04-16, 40.00, 45.00, 2],
                 ['B','3', 2015-04-18, 45.00, 45.00, 30],
                 ['B','4', 2015-07-25, 5.00, 10.00, 55]],
                 columns=['dept','sku', 'date', 'price', 'orig_price', 'days_at_price'])
print(df)

   dept sku        date   price orig_price days_at_price
0     A   1  2015-02-01   20.00      20.00             5
1     A   1  2015-02-06   16.00      20.00             8
2     A   1  2015-02-14   14.00      20.00            34
3     A   1  2015-03-20   20.00      20.00             5
4     A   1  2015-03-25   15.00      20.00            15
5     A   2  2015-02-01   75.99     100.00            22
6     A   2  2015-02-23  100.00     100.00            30
7     A   2  2015-03-25   65.00     100.00            64
8     B   3  2015-04-01   45.00      45.00            15
9     B   3  2015-04-16   40.00      45.00             2
10    B   3  2015-04-18   45.00      45.00            30
11    B   4  2015-07-25    5.00      10.00            55
```

I want to describe the pricing cycles, which can be defined as the period when a sku goes from original price to promotional price (or multiple promotional prices) and returns to original. A cycle must start with the original price. It is okay to include cycles which never change in price, as well as those that are reduced and never return. But an initial price that is less than orig_price would not be counted as a cycle. For the above df, the result I am looking for is:

```
 dept sku cycle orig_price_days promo_days
0   A   1     1               5         42
1   A   1     2               5         15
2   A   2     1              30         64
3   B   3     1              15          2
4   B   3     2              30          0
```

I played around with groupby and sum, but can't quite figure out how to define a cycle and total the rows accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As specified in your example, `date`, `price`, `orig_price`, and `days_at_price` are all strings. I'm not sure if that's what you want... (so is `sku`, but that seems less an issue.)

Comment: thanks @pml, that was inadvertent. fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `loc` instead of `groupby` - you want chunks of skus over time periods, not aggregated groups. A for-loop, used in moderation, can also help here and won't be particularly un-pandas like. (At least if, like me, you consider looping over unique array slices to be fine.)

```
df['cycle'] = -1  # create a column for the cycle
skus = df.sku.unique()  # get unique skus for iteration

for sku in skus:
    # Get the start date for each cycle for this sku
    # NOTE that we define cycles as beginning
    #   when the price equals the original price
    # This avoids the mentioned issue that a cycle should not start
    #   if initial is less than original.
    cycle_start_dates = df.loc[(df.sku == sku]) & \
                               (df.price == df.orig_price),
                               'date'].tolist()

    # append a terminal date
    cycle_start_dates.append(df.date.max()+timedelta(1))

    # Assign the cycle values
    for i in range(len(cycle_start_dates) - 1):
        df.loc[(df.sku == sku) & \
               (cycle_start_dates[i] <= df.date) & \
               (df.date < cycle_start_dates[i+1]), 'cycle'] = i+1
```

This should give you a column with all of the cycles for each sku:

```
   dept sku       date   price  orig_price  days_at_price  cycle
0     A   1 2015-02-01   20.00        20.0              5      1
1     A   1 2015-02-06   16.00        20.0              8      1
2     A   1 2015-02-14   14.00        20.0             34      1
3     A   1 2015-03-20   20.00        20.0              5      2
4     A   1 2015-03-25   15.00        20.0             15      2
5     A   2 2015-02-01   75.99       100.0             22      1
6     A   2 2015-02-23  100.00       100.0             30      1
7     A   2 2015-03-25   65.00       100.0             64      2
8     B   3 2015-04-01   45.00        45.0             15      2
9     B   3 2015-04-16   40.00        45.0              2      2
10    B   3 2015-04-18   45.00        45.0             30      2
11    B   4 2015-07-25    5.00        10.0             55      2
```

Once you have the `cycle` column, aggregation becomes relatively straightforward. This multiple aggregation:

```
df.groupby(['dept', 'sku','cycle'])['days_at_price']\
  .agg({'orig_price_days': lambda x: x[:1].sum(),
        'promo_days': lambda x: x[1:].sum()
       })\
  .reset_index()
```

will give you the desired result:

```
  dept sku  cycle  promo_days  orig_price_days
0    A   1      1          42                5
1    A   1      2          15                5
2    A   2     -1           0               22
3    A   2      1          64               30
4    B   3      1           2               15
5    B   3      2           0               30
6    B   4     -1           0               55
```

Note that this has additional `-1` values for `cycle` for pre-cycle, below original pricing.

Comment: Thanks @pml - using loc indexing for chunking the skus makes sense. I should have mentioned that my full set has several million rows. I'm applying this to it now, but it is taking a long time to get through the nested loop. Is there a way to accomplish the cycle start dates faster?

Comment: Look at the `ffill` method for [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) - assign the starting value for the `cycle` - e.g. 1, 2, 3 for each interval, and then fill the column downward with the assigned cycle value.
Alternately, you could split the dataframe by location and then parallelize the process. Since each location slice will be independent, that should also be straightforward. Look up the [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Alternately, you could combine the `(df.sku == sku) & \
               (cycle_start_dates[i] <= df.date) & \
               (df.date < cycle_start_dates[i+1])` as a single lambda function: `lambda x: x['sku'] == sku and  cycle_start_dates[i] <= x['date'] < cycle_start_dates[i+1]`. That should get through the rows a bit more quickly.

Comment: Thanks @pml for the tips/tricks. I used some of them to get very close to my answer, which I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

I got very close to producing the desired end result...

```
# add a column to track whether price is above/below/equal to orig
df.loc[:,'reg'] = np.sign(df.price - df.orig_price)

# remove row where first known price for sku is promo
df_gp = df.groupby(['dept', 'sku'])
df = df[~((df_gp.cumcount() == 0) & (df.reg == -1))]

# enumerate all the individual pricing cycles
df.loc[:,'cycle'] = (df.reg == 0).cumsum()

# group/aggregate to get days at orig vs. promo pricing
cycles = df.groupby(['dept', 'sku', 'cycle'])['days_at_price'].agg({'promo_days': lambda x: x[1:].sum(), 'reg_days':lambda x: x[:1].sum()})

print cycles.reset_index()

  dept  sku  cycle  reg_days  promo_days
0    A    1      1         5          42
1    A    1      2         5          15
2    A    2      3        30          64
3    B    3      4        15           2
4    B    3      5        30           0
```

The only part that I couldn't quite crack was how to restart the cycle number for each sku before the groupby.